# Rotation puzzle game animation frame

Tags: xcode, animation, frame, puzzle

I'm building a puzzle game called Rotation. Rotation has one table 3x3 with numbers 1-9 in it and the users tried to put the numbers in the right order rotating the 4 of them (one set). So in my UI, i have 9 UIImgaeViews an 4 buttons to do the rotation of the sets.

In the first set of images i have the following code to do the animation part of rotation:

```
-(void)animateNumbers
{
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
  //[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
  [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

  CGRect pos00Frame = img1.frame;
  CGRect pos01Frame = img2.frame;
  CGRect pos10Frame = img5.frame;
  CGRect pos11Frame = img4.frame;

  img1.frame = pos01Frame;
  img4.frame = pos00Frame;
  img5.frame = pos10Frame;
  img2.frame = pos11Frame;

  [UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

My problem is when i random all the 9 numbers in the game, i can't do the rotation part of this function because i don't know which picture is in the set. So my function isn't working properly. In some way, i have to know where & which are the numbers in the UI at any time! I tried to tag them but no progress with that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you mean, but you can tag the images, then get them again using:

```
UIImageView * currentImage = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

it doesn't matter if you use 2 variables to access one image view.

Ex:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
imageView.tag = 1;

}

 //then in your other action:

-(void)animateNumbers {
                                              //or whatever the image tag is
UIImageView * currentImage = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```